# Form OnSubmit to wait jQuery Ajax Return?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, return, onsubmit

I want to trigger `$.ajax` on form `onsubmit` and `return true` only after Ajax return is something valid.

For example:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return ajaxValidation();">
    <input id="myString" name="myString" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In Javascript:

```
function ajaxValidation() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { myString: $("#myString").val() }
    }).success(function( response ) {
        alert(response); //Got 'ok'
        if (response=="ok") {
            return true; //mark-1
        } else {
            alert("Oh, string is wrong. Form Submit is cancelled.");
        }
    });
    return false; //mark-2
}
```

When i submit, i got alert `ok`, but it returned 'false' because it jumped to final `return false` line.

Why? I can not understand. Actually, it should hit to `return true` line. (And, even after `return true`, the function should stop there and just come out of it)

So it is now means, the parent function `does NOT wait` to the Ajax Return. Instead, it is continuously running down to the end. Any idea why, please. How to make the parent function to be waiting the Ajax?

Comment: There is only one return that will affect the ajaxValidation function and that is the one marked 2,the rest are in another function.

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171642/jquery-validate-email-via-ajax-before-submitting-form-also-via-ajax

Answer (score 4):

Since AJAX is asynchronous your validation Would work better using a click handler on the submit button.

Following is based on removing the inline `onSubmit`

```
$(function() {

    var $form = $('#myForm');

    $form.find('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           /* async: false,  this is deprecated*/
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
                myString: $("#myString").val()
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            alert(response); //Got 'ok'
            if(response == "ok") {
             /*  submit the form*/
                $form.submit();
            } else {
                alert("Oh, string is wrong. Form Submit is cancelled.");
            }
        }); /* prevent default when submit button clicked*/
        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: It will work. But i want to handle the real form `OnSubmit` event.

Comment: gets  more complicated doing it that way. What is reason for needing to use `onSubmit`?

Comment: because, form `submit` event is ONLY controlled-by/ depend-on that button. Not the real `submit` handle, of the `<form>` element.

Comment: have no idea what that means. Can submit a form using code too, works just as well. WHat you are wanting to do comes before submit, so makes just as much sense not to include it in submit handler

Comment: obviously, there may be spam bot, if your submission event is only handled by that button, which is not the real submit handle. `OnSubmit` is the final handler, whatever the form has been submitted by pressing a button or hit the enter in a text field or, even by the bot scripts. Your way, the form submit is only handled by that button, where how if i press enter on other input fields? How if bots trigger the submit anyway?

Comment: what are you smoking? You can't rely on javascript to protect anything. It can be turned off easily by user, or spammer can easily run script on page themselves and fill the form and submit it without typing anything or touching the form controls. The only real protection is at server. Even with your ajax validation you MUST re validate everything again at server

Comment: okayyy, whatever, handling on `OnSubmit` event can't be done by that `$.ajax` way, righttt??

Comment: Hey, old question, I realize that, but I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054087/811240) with a way to bind to the actual form submit event in case anyone reading this is interested. I wouldn't say this would help against bots, but it could handle the event that a user pushes the enter key while on one of the form fields to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Return value at mark 1 is for your success function of ajax request, not for your validation function. Therefore even if it returns it returns only from there and not from validation function which is mark 2

Comment: So i'm curious can i just return the whole `$.ajax`? I mean, `return $.ajax({......});` since from the start, then move `mark-2` into the `else` block? Returning the, whole Ajax Return?