# How to check for matching email in XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I'm trying to get this code to work, i'm sure its a small error. I need to check the XML for an email address and match against the user's entered email on a form. Where am i going wrong?

Do i need to clean the code before it is entered into the XML initially (it is done via another form)?? Thank you for any help given!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
<customer>
    <custid>1</custid>
    <firstname>ben</firstname>
    <lastname>ben1</lastname>
    <email>ben@gmail.com</email>
    <password>ben</password>
    <phone>0200000000</phone>
</customer>
</customers>
```

HTML & INLINE JAVASCRIPT

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Existing Customer Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Existing Customer Login Page</h1>
<fieldset>
        <form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return loadDoc()">
            <legend>
                Email: <input type='email' name='email' id="email" />
                <br><br>
                Password: <input type='password' name='password' 
                 id="password"  />
                <br><br>
                <input type='Submit' value='Log In' />
            </legend>
        </form>
</fieldset>
<!--Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadDoc()
{
email = document.getElementById('email');
password = document.getElementById('password');

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
    {
        alert('Connected!');
        myFunction(xhttp);
    }
}
xhttp.open("GET", "data/customer.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}


function myFunction(xml) 
{
var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("customer");
alert(xml.responseXML);
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue 
==   document.getElementById('email')) 
    {
        alert('Success, you have logged in!');
        return (true);
    }
    alert('Failed to log in');
    document.myForm.email.focus();
    return false;
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that your customers password in clear text, that you are downloading to the client before matching? You do know that anyone who visits that page would be able to inspect the traffic and login as any of your customers right?

Comment: It is for an assignment, no security needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this does what you are looking for:

What if you change:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return loadDoc()">
```

To

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
```

And change:

```
<input type='Submit' value='Log In' />
```

To

```
<input type='Submit' value='Log In' onclick="loadDoc(); return false;"/>
```

And then change:

```
==   document.getElementById('email'))
```

To:

```
==   document.getElementById('email').value)
```

Maybe [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541325/form-onsubmit-to-wait-jquery-ajax-return) can give your more information

// Edit as a response to your comment

You can access the other xml elements inside the loop for example like this:

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("customer");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        var emailFromXml;
        var passwordFromXml;
        var emailFromForm = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var passwordFromForm = document.getElementById('password').value;

        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0]) {
            console.log("email: " + email);
            emailFromXml = x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("password")[0]) {
            passwordFromXml = x[i].getElementsByTagName("password")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }

        if (emailFromXml == emailFromForm && passwordFromXml == passwordFromForm) {
            alert('Success, you have logged in as ' + emailFromForm  + '!');
            return (true);
        }
    }
    alert('Failed to log in');
    document.myForm.email.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i now see that onclick works better. However it only looks at the first entry in XML, i cannot get it query the other entries for matches?

Comment: Sure you can, I've updated my answer with a code example.
Does that example answer your question?

Comment: That makes it clearer, but unfortunately does not help. In my XML i added 2 extra sets of data, one for john and one for mark. Neither are working, it seems it just reads the first index of the first set of data... ??

Comment: Ah I see, I've updated the example. Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for your help! Works perfectly.

Comment: Can i ask you one more question, i need to retrieve the customer id form the XML for the email that matches the form email. Do you know how i might go about doing this?