# onsubmit return false is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following script shows the error message correctly, but the form always submits whether `confirm_shop_code()` returns `true` or `false`. I tried in many ways to solve the bug but it still persists. I have to stop the form from submitting when it returns `false`, but allow it to submit when it returns `true`. Please can any one help me to solve this?

```
<h2 id="shop_data"></h2>
<!-- form -->
<form action="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm_shop_code();">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shop" name="code" value="<?php echo $account->code; ?>" placeholder="Enter Shop Code">

    </div>
</form>
<!-- validation script -->
<script>
        function confirm_shop_code(){
            var code=document.getElementById( "shop" ).value;

            if(code) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'validations.php',
                    data: {
                        shop_code:code,
                    },

                    success: function (response) {
                        $( '#shop_data' ).html(response);

                        if(response=="OK") {
                            return true;    
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $( '#shop_data' ).html("");
                return false;
            }
        }    

    </script>

<!-- php code -->

<?php 
include "system_load.php";
$code = $_POST['shop_code'];
global $db;
$query = "SELECT code from accounts WHERE code='".$code."'";
$result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count > 0) {
    echo "SHOP CODE already Exists";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Because of the using of asynchronous ajax. Try to add `async: false` to ajax option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form OnSubmit to wait jQuery Ajax Return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541325/form-onsubmit-to-wait-jquery-ajax-return)

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is submitting is because AJAX calls are asynchronous by default. I wouldn't suggest making it synchronous because this will block the rest of the javascript execution. Also, you are returning `false` from the `success` method of `$.ajax`. This is not in the same scope as the parent function and therefore does not also cause the parent function to return `false`. So in fact, your `confirm_shop_code()` function is not returning *anything* unless `code` is false and that's why your form is always being submitted, no matter what happens with the AJAX call.

I would recommend using jQuery to bind to the form's submit event and just disable form submitting with `preventDefault()`. First, just add an `id` attribute to the form (e.g. `"yourform"`) and do something like:

```
$("form#yourform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    var code=document.getElementById( "shop" ).value;

    if(code) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'validations.php',
            data: {
                shop_code:code,
            },

            success: function (response) {
                $( '#shop_data' ).html(response);
                if(response=="OK") {
                    form.unbind('submit').submit()
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $( '#shop_data' ).html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's the default submit action?

Comment: @TerryWei Oh, I misread the question. I thought OP wanted it to not submit ever. I'll edit it.

Comment: @TerryWei Done.

Comment: I followed what you said above. but it didn't works. In previous it actually shows error message then submit. in this form submits directly

Comment: @Ganesh This code will only submit the form if the response returned is `"OK"`, otherwise it doesn't. If this is not the behavior you want, please clarify and I will edit the answer.

Comment: What you write on above is exact my requirement. But this code submits both cases if the response returned is "OK" or not.

Comment: @Ganesh It works for me without submitting the form: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/344776/. Make sure you're removing the `onsubmit` attribute from the HTML because that will conflict with the jquery. As a general rule, you should try not to put ANY javascript in your HTML code, including things like calling an `onsubmit` function. Keep HTML, JS, and CSS separate.

Comment: Thanks for your support, But i solved this problem using Another way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `async:false` to your ajax code

```
function confirm_shop_code(){
    var code=document.getElementById( "shop" ).value;
    var stopSubmit = false;

    if(code) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'validations.php',
            async:false,
            data: {
                shop_code:code,
            },

            success: function (response) {
                $( '#shop_data' ).html(response);

                if(response=="OK") {
                    stopSubmit = false;    
                } else {
                    stopSubmit = true;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $( '#shop_data' ).html("");
        stopSubmit = true;
    }
    if(stopSubmit){
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this async:false, but again form is submitting

Comment: @Ganesh updated my answer,you need not return directly in `success` callback function

Answer (score 0):

You should call ***return false;*** function on the click event of the submit button.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="return false;" class="btn btn-primary col-4">Proceed</button>
```

or you can use:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
//your logic here

//this return false will not work here     
return false;
//this will work
e.preventDefault();
            
});
```