# It is not able to post with JS form submit function

Tags: javascript, php, post, forms, html-input

In this webpage , I have a visible form with a submit button ,called form A.It has a post action.

`<form name="payFormCcard"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">`

I want to do an invisible form that extract some of the data from form A , with the method of hidden input button .It auto-executes the form and post to the another place with the JS.

However, it works and posts to appropriate place  if I add the real button .

```
 <input type="submit" name="submission_button" value="Click here if the site is taking too long to redirect!">
```

Here is my code (without the real button):

```
   <form name="A"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">  <== first visable form 
    .....
    //invisible table
      <form name="payForm" method="post" action=" https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">

      <input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="sth">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="</?php echo $input_amount; ?>" >

    <input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="<?php  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Taipei");  $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); echo $date ; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="sth" >
    <input type="hidden" name="mpsMode" value="sth" >
    <input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="http://www.yourdomain.com/Success.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="http://www.yourdomain.com/Fail.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="http://www.yourdomain.com/Cancel.html">
   ...

    <!--     <input type="submit" name="submission_button" value="Click here if the site is taking too long to redirect!">-->
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Our form submission function.
        function submitForm() {
            document.getElementById('payForm').submit();
        }
        //Call the function submitForm() as soon as the page has loaded.
        window.onload = submitForm;

    </script>
```

Comment: I don't see any id `payForm` in your element . Never use nested form !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form OnSubmit to wait jQuery Ajax Return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541325/form-onsubmit-to-wait-jquery-ajax-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) instead of [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) to ensure that the DOM elements are loaded successfully.

Try to do something like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Our form submission function.
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById('payForm').submit();
    }
    //Call the function submitForm() as soon as the document has loaded.

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        submitForm();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind start from `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: OK, done. haven't tried yet. would you please take a test for me?

Comment: Not working with no snytax error.Still cannot post the method . Btw Singaporean ?

Comment: OK..I found the problem is that you didn't set the `ID` to the `form`...

Comment: No, I'm Taiwanese.

Comment: Thanks , I m Hong Kongese

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173858/discussion-between-terry-wei-and-evabb).