# Javascript is not waiting for AJAX Error to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I am having trouble with ordering some Javascript AJAX interactions.

I have a form where a user enter's a gamertag (`summonerName`). I then AJAX to the game's API to get that user's `ID`.

However, if it is an invalid name (a GET error `GET url 404 Not Found`) my JS events continue on before even waiting for the AJAX `error` to finish.

So after the form submits I then get my notification saying an error occurred which is too late by then to halt the form.

I would have figured that the `error` function would hold priority just like the `success` function in that all my scripts should wait until it has finished.

```
var good = true; // if false will halt form when it reaches submission function
var summoner = $('#createSummonerName').val().trim();
var summonerID = "";
    if (summoner != "" && summonerID == "") {
            var ID = "";
            ID = summoner;
            var YOURKEY = "(key)";
            alert("checking");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + ID + '?api_key=' + YOURKEY,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {

                    },
                    success: function (json) {
                        var userID = ID.replace(" ", "");
                        userID = userID.toLowerCase().trim();
                        summonerIDpull = json[userID].id;
                        summonerID = summonerIDpull;
                        alert("found");
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        summonerID = "";
                        alert("not found");
                        document.getElementById("createSummonerName").className = document.getElementById("createSummonerName").className + " error";
                        good = false;

                    }
                });
    }
    // more functions that validate and submit the form
```

So what happens is that the form will submit and the `alert("not found");` occurs a second after that if a GET error occurs. :(

Is there anyway to get a error/issue/exception and make the script wait until that error has been processed? Because of the error's delay my `good = false;` line does not run until after the form has been submitted which is bad.

I am still very new to AJAX so sorry if this is a simple answer and I am misunderstanding some concepts.

Comment: Your JavaScript is *supposed* to continue on without waiting for AJAX to return. That's what AJAX is all about. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/866654/901048) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12171642/901048) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18977234/901048) about how to make your form `submit` wait for the AJAX callback.

Comment: I'm a bit list here. The processing of that error is fully completed when you get the alert message. Is it that the rest of your script that validates is being processed immediately and isn't waiting on the `good = false`?